# How can I make this insertion sort method run one step at a time?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to animate this method visually, and I want to use a timer to control the insertion sort by letting it check one index or swap one set of indices every so often (100ms). This way I can see it play out step by step.

Here is the method:

```
public static void sort(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j = i;
        while(j > 0 && arr[j] < arr[j-1]){
            ArrayUtility.swap(j,j-1, arr);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

The goal of this is so that if one pair of indices is checked against each other, the method doesn't continue to loop through, it checks the indices and then stops until the next part of the method is allowed to run 100ms later.

Comment: Either remember the step you were at (indices `i` and `j`), then you can pause and resume. Or just sleep inline at the position you want to, `Thread.sleep(100)`.

Comment: For former, you could create a class `Sorter` which has an `int i` and `int j` field and the array. Then this class provides a `sortStep()` method which only sorts one step. Therefore, it will simply use the `i` and `j` field and do the next step and then advance `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Remember the current `i` and `j` indices, then you can easily pause and resume at any time by *extracting* all possible single steps out of your loop construction, that is:

- Regular inner loop iteration
- Inner loop has finished, advancing outer loop
- Outer loop has finished, algorithm done

I would create a class `Sorter` which has those indices and the array as fields, then you can provide a simple `sortStep` method which only executes one step and updates the indices.

---

### Solution

```
public class Sorter {
    private final int[] values;
    private int i = 1;
    private int j = 1;

    public Sorter(int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    // @returns Whether sorting algorithm has finished
    public boolean sortStep() {
        if (i >= values.length) {
            // Outer loop has finished
            return true;
        }

        if (j > 0 && values[j] < values[j - 1]) {
            // Inner loop iteration
            ArrayUtility.swap(j, j - 1, values);
            j--;
        } else {
            // Inner loop has finished, outer loop iteration
            i++;
            j = i;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call `sortStep` in a loop until its done:

```
int[] values = ...
Sorter sorter = new Sorter(values);

while (!sorter.sortStep()) {
    // Animate
    displayValues(values);
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Or connect the method to some nice pause and resume buttons of your UI.

---

### Notes

If you do not want to treat

- Regular inner loop iteration
- Inner loop has finished, advancing outer loop

as two separate steps, but as one step, you can simply move the case out of the `if-else` construct and do it directly after inner iteration:

```
if (j > 0 && values[j] < values[j - 1]) {
    // Inner loop iteration
    ArrayUtility.swap(j, j - 1, avaluesrr);
    j--;
}

if (j <= 0 || values[j] >= values[j - 1]) {
    // Inner loop has finished, outer loop iteration
    i++;
    j = i;
}
```

Similarly you can put the *done*-detection to the end of the method to have the method output `true` at the moment when its really done. That way, you do not have to call it again with no effect:

```
// Duplicated at the end of sortStep
if (i >= values.length) {
    // Outer loop has finished
    return true;
}
```